# Preserve UVs when modifying topology

Tags: modeling, uv, geometry

First question here. I came from a 3DSMax background, since then I've succeeded to find pretty much everything I needed to make the switch from 3DSMax to Blender, except for this : there a very useful option called "preserve UVs" that allows to move vertices / edges /faces without stretching the mapped texture on the mesh. In fact it moves the selection simultaneously in 3D view and UV view.

As far as I know, actually the only way to "Preserve UVs" in Blender is to use the "Slide Edge" tool and select the "Correct UVs" option. I would like to know if there's any workaround to apply this "Correct UVs" option when moving elements in 3D view

Is this a planned feature for the further Blender's updates? Actually it's a kind a straight forward workflow, modeling everything, we have to make sure that everything is ok before Unwrapping UVs. It would be nice to have a way to going back and forth easily.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I think UV correction added to vertex slide in 2.74 too.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I've tested it. It's a way to do it, but it's not as simple as having this kind of option activated when moving around vertices or edges in the 3D view with the 3D manipulator.
Here we have to use a specific tool to do it.
I guess I'll have to do it this way until this kind of option will be available.

Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: You can use live UV unwrap and pin vertices on the edges of UV islands or minimize stretch to correct the distortion.

Comment: (Late answer). Yeah, this is a good method for complex and organic shapes. I'm actually working on a low poly environment and there's no way to use this.
Here is two examples in Blender and 3DSMax to show how this could be useful, especially when you have to map an environment on a pre-made texture :

[Blender](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74032860/Blender.webm)

[3DSMax](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74032860/3DSMax.webm)

Comment: @J0hnD03 for flat surfaces like those you are dealing with try the **UV Project** modifer.

Comment: @J0hnD03 here's an example http://gfycat.com/BogusBoldGenet

Answer (score 14):

In the following animation I'm double-tapping the <kbd>g</kbd> key to move points and edges.

[image]

In the video, an entire corner piece was moved and I don't think this can be easily done using Blender yet.  There may be an Addon for this, I'm not sure.

As mentioned in the comments above, the UV Project Modifier can be useful and there is also a way to do something similar in Cycles.

It's called Box Mapping and uses the Texture Coordinates node to create coordinates using various methods, in this case I used the Object Coordinates.  This way, you can edit the mesh all you like without affecting the texture and then once you have the model ready, you can bake the box mapped texture to the UV coordinates.

Here is a quick Cycles render that shows Blended Box Mapping in Action.

[image]

This is just a plain cube with no UV coordinates.  There are 3 other cubes that are being used as Boolean Objects on the cube that is being rendered.  The next image shows the node and model setup for the brick box looking thing

[image]

You can pretty much do whatever you want to this model and not have to worry about the UV Coordinates.

[image]

Finally, the Booleans are applied, the model is unwrapped and the texture is baked.

[image]

---

Now back to the original question.  Loop Cut and Slide <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> can be set to maintain UV's.  The Inset tool does this as well<kbd>i</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

When moving edges/vertices (with g+g) check "Correct UV" in options shelf
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Or press <kbd>G</kbd> three times.

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUjbmlgxhXk which shows an example